# Pinning one package breaks the graph

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

I am pinning django to a specific, older version:

```
...
[packages]
...
Django = "==1.10.8"
```

I can not install:

```
$ pipenv install

Could not find a version that matches Django==1.10.8,>=1.11,>=1.6,>=1.7,>=1.8,>=1.8.7
```

Well, of course, those constraints are mutually exclusive. So I force a install anyway, to take a look at the graph:

```
$ pipenv install --skip-lock
```

And now taking a look at the graph:

```
django-allauth==0.35.0
  - Django [required: >=1.11, installed: 1.10.8]
  - python3-openid [required: >=3.0.8, installed: 3.1.0]
    - defusedxml [required: Any, installed: 0.5.0]
  - requests [required: Any, installed: 2.18.4]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2018.4.16]
    - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.4]
    - idna [required: >=2.5,<2.7, installed: 2.6]
    - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.23, installed: 1.22]
  - requests-oauthlib [required: >=0.3.0, installed: 0.8.0]
    - oauthlib [required: >=0.6.2, installed: 2.0.7]
    - requests [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 2.18.4]
      - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2018.4.16]
      - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.4]
      - idna [required: >=2.5,<2.7, installed: 2.6]
      - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.23, installed: 1.22]
```

(this happens with several packages)

What should I do now? What I think will solve my issue is:

- search for all packages which are requiring a version higher than the one I want
- take a look at the homepages of those packages, and see if I can use an older version with lower requirements, matching my current max requirements for django

This seems very cumbersome, and besides seems that is something that could  be automatically solved by `pipenv`.

Is there an easier solution than pinning several packages manually? Ideally I would like to pin only django, and let `pipenv` do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pin Django to version 1.10.8 you cannot also pin django-allauth to version 0.35 as following version requires at least Django 1.11, so you need to use for instance 0.34 or set in requirements.txt not to pin exact django-allauth version

Comment: Sure, been there, done that. And for all the other packages that are breaking the graph, I did that too. My question is whether there is a better solution than manually pinning the packages which cause conflict, and whether `pipenv` has the capability of detecting these kind of issues by itself.

Comment: I would suggest reading docs issue part https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988

Unfortunately for now there is no "true" dependency resolution which would get rid of some manual work

Comment: Btw, maybe it was not clear on my question, but django-allauth is not pinned at all in the Pipfile. In fact the only pinned requirement is django itself. The rest is set to '*'. That is why I am surprised that pipenv uses the last version.